# XML To CSV Coop Project

Tags: python, xml, csv

Now I found a problem during work.
I need XML data from http://air4thai.pcd.go.th/services/getAQI_XML.php?region=2
I want to parse XML And output to CSV

And im newbie in python 
now im test coding parsing PM10 like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import os
Air4thaiURL = 'http://air4thai.pcd.go.th/services/getAQI_XML.php?region=2'
resp = requests.get(Air4thaiURL)
msg = resp.content
tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
for station in tree.findall('.//station/LastUpdate'):
print ('{}'.format(
station.get('PM10')))
```

BUT result like this

None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

So, it's must displayed in Value / Im try to type :s it's result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gistda59\Desktop\Coop - Python Script\pm10_XML.py", line 11, in <module>
    station.get('PM10')))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

how to solve it's and advise me to parsing XML to CSV from this URL 
thank you so much to help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import os
Air4thaiURL = 'http://air4thai.pcd.go.th/services/getAQI_XML.php?region=2'
resp = requests.get(Air4thaiURL)
msg = resp.content
tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
for station in tree.findall('.//station/LastUpdate'):
    if station.tag == 'LastUpdate':
        for item in station:
            if item.tag == 'PM10':
                print(item.attrib)
```